# Foreign Key Constraint in child table allows to insert values that doesn't exists in the parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, constraints

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have defined a foreign key constraint on a table. The foreign key references composite primary key. The fk constraint does not work when one column has '00000' and other column is null. The parent table does not contain '00000'. Both of the fk columns have `varchar` data type.

[image]

Below is the example:

```
INSERT INTO XYZ
    ([BUSINESS_PARTNER_ID]
    ,[INDUSTRY_TYPE_CDE]
    ,[INDUSTRY_SUBTYPE_CDE])
VALUES
    (1,
    Null
    '00000')
GO
```

The industry type and industry sub type column is referenced from another table.
Below is the script:

```
ALTER TABLE [nfs].[xyz] WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_BPMAIN__ITCDE_ISTCDE] 
FOREIGN KEY([INDUSTRY_TYPE_CDE], [INDUSTRY_SUBTYPE_CDE]) 
REFERENCES [nfs].[abc] ([INDUSTRY_TYPE_CDE], [INDUSTRY_SUBTYPE_CDE]) 
GO 

ALTER TABLE [nfs].[xyz] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BPMAIN__ITCDE_ISTCDE] 
GO
```

SQL Server does not give any error on insertion. It inserts the value in the child table. According to my understanding, the fk columns can be null or should contain values that exist in the parent table.

Comment: Can you script out your FK and post it? I wasn't aware that a FK could be on two columns. Is the problem that you shouldn't be allowed to enter NULLs?

Comment: other than what Nick mentioned ,please post the error as well

Comment: Please expand on 'does not work'. Do you mean it shouldn't let you insert this child record? I'm still curious as to how you define a FK on two columns

Comment: ALTER TABLE [nfs].[xyz]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BPMAIN__ITCDE_ISTCDE] FOREIGN KEY([INDUSTRY_TYPE_CDE], [INDUSTRY_SUBTYPE_CDE])
REFERENCES [nfs].[abc] ([INDUSTRY_TYPE_CDE], [INDUSTRY_SUBTYPE_CDE])
GO

ALTER TABLE [nfs].[xyz] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BPMAIN__ITCDE_ISTCDE]
GO

Comment: The Sql server does not give any error. It inserts the value in the child table.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] - this means sample tables DDL, sample data as DML, and desired output.

Comment: Unfortunately, when one or more columns is `NULL`, the foreign key isn't checked. You need to revise your design to one which doesn't use `NULL`s as if they're actual values.

Comment: As per my investigation, composite primary key columns(one or more) cannot be null. So why does the fk constraint isn't checked  when one or more column contains null? Can you please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why does the fk constraint isn't checked when one or more column contains null? Can you please explain this behavior?

First, we have the *practical* reasons. Foreign keys are maintained and checked using indexes. In order for an index to be usable, we need to know the (sought for) values of all columns within the index. If we have an index/pk on `(a,b)` and we have a foreign key value of `(NULL,1)`, we cannot *seek* within the index in order to determine whether there is any row with a `b` value of 1. This would make the foreign key "expensive" to maintain.

But secondly, we need to consider consistency. For the single column case, its fairly uncontroversial - if you have a value in the FK column, then there needs to be a matching value in the referenced column. Otherwise, if the FK column is `NULL` then the constraint isn't checked.

But, how do we extend this to multiple columns? What *is* the rule above? There's not a *single* obvious interpretation, but instead multiple ones. Is the above rule "if *all* columns are non-NULL, then the constraint is checked" or "if *any* columns are non-NULL, then the constraint is checked"? These rules are identical when only a single column is under consideration.

You expected the rule to be the second one, when it is in fact the first. This is explicitly [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx):

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint can contain null values; however, if any column of a composite FOREIGN KEY constraint contains null values, verification of all values that make up the FOREIGN KEY constraint is skipped. To make sure that all values of a composite FOREIGN KEY constraint are verified, specify NOT NULL on all the participating columns.

Answer (score 2):

While you really should have provided a complete example as Zohar Peled said, it is likely that your problem lies in the `WITH NOCHECK` option in the foreign key definition. It should be `CHECK` to make the foreign key enabled and enforced by the engine. The way it is, the constraint is not trusted.

See [What is lost when I create a Foreign Key using `WITH NOCHECK`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114411/what-is-lost-when-i-create-a-foreign-key-using-with-nocheck) for examples what happens when you use this option.

Comment: In my foreign key script, first I have defined the constraint with no check. After creating the constraint, check constraint is defined on the fk.

Comment: @Damien has provided a correct answer. I didn't have a clue that composite foreign keys behave in this way with NULLs.